# Parsing JSON response from api using Java containing multiple JSON arrays

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have the following JSON from an API response. I need capture the name & origin for Level 1, Level 11, Level 111 & Level 1111. This might increase or decrease based on the order we place in the application. When the number of levels are fixed, i am able to parse and get the name & origin using JSON parser, but if this keep changing how do i address that. JSON response below -

```
"root": {
    "name": "Test",
    "version": 1,
    "type": "process",
    "steps": [{
        "name": "Level 1",
        "origin": "Origin1",
        "type": "step",
        "state": "complete",
        "steps": []
    }, {
        "name": "Level 2",
        "origin": "Origin2",
        "type": "step",
        "state": "complete",
        "steps": []
    }, {
        "name": "Level 3",
        "origin": "Origin3",
        "type": "process",
        "state": "error",
        "steps": [{
            "name": "Level 11",
            "origin": "origin 11",
            "type": "step",
            "state": "complete",
            "steps": []
        }, {
            "name": "Level 12",
            "origin": "origin 12",
            "type": "step",
            "state": "complete",
            "operation": "fulfill",
            "steps": []
        }, {
            "name": "Level 13",
            "origin": "origin 13",
            "type": "process",
            "state": "error",
            "steps": [{
                    "name": "Level 111",
                    "origin": "origin 111",
                    "type": "step",
                    "state": "complete",
                    "steps": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Level 112",
                    "origin": "Origin 112",
                    "type": "process",
                    "state": "complete",
                    "steps": [{
                        "name": "Level 1111",
                        "origin": "origin 1111",
                        "type": "step",
                        "state": "complete",
                        "steps": []
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Jackson can handle this

Comment: Are you able to share the code that you are using for the fixed data? Because from the sample you have shared, this looks like a recursive structure that expands on steps only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), you can traverse the entire tree using a method like this one:

```
public static void parse(JSONArray arg) {
    for (int i = 0; i<arg.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(arg.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
        System.out.println(arg.getJSONObject(i).getString("origin"));
        parse (arg.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("steps"));
    }
}
```

From the code, you can see that I am only displaying name and Origin. There is a recursive call the traverses each steps array. Once you get the initial object object (assuming you are using the variable response), you can then just call the parse method:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject jo_root = jo.getJSONObject("root");
parse(jo_root.getJSONArray("steps"));
```

I am sure you know how to only print the ones you want from here.

Comment: Thank you for this... It worked fine with this approach